# how to make h2 with second click and h3 to h6 with thirth and so forth click on button?

Tags: javascript

```js
let index = 1

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.getElementById('btnKnop1').addEventListener('click', () => {
    let newElement = document.createElement('h1');
    let node = document.getElementById('txtElement').value;
    let newNode = document.createTextNode(node)
    newElement.appendChild(newNode)
    console.log(newElement)
    document.getElementById('divResult').appendChild(newElement)
  })
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtElement">
<button id="btnKnop1">Toevoegen koptekst</button>
<div id="divResult"></div>
```

how to make h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 appear on page with following button clicks?

Above is what i have now working with only one click.
It gets an h1 to appear, but no following ones.
It needs to appear h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 and back to h1 with each button click.

Comment: `document.createElement('h' + index)`. And then see to it, that you increment `index` each time, and reset it back to `1` if it becomes greater than `6`.

Comment: Or use the [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) to avoid the need to test and reset the index

Comment: how do i increment and reset it back to 1?

Comment: could you please add the whole code as a comment. thanks allot!